# Buffer Overflow a Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, buffer-overflow

I am attempting to create a buffer-overflow-proof program and I was considering using an stl vector for this, but I have read that this still would not perform bounds checking and could still be hacked. I am mainly concerned about overriding a return or function call or another variable in my program. Would a vector work in this case?

Comment: ***I have read that this still would not perform bounds checking*** It will if you use .at()

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking here. Are you hoping for the compiler to issue a warning if it detects an out-of-range index upon compilation? Or, are you wanting an `out_of_range` exception to be thrown at run time when an attempt is made to access an index outside of the `vectors` range?

Comment: Any code could be hackable if there's a bug in it. Using containers with bounds checking helps, but it doesn't magically make your code hack proof, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a vector like this

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

This is an empty `vector` of `int`s called `v`. It has 0 elements. Attempting to access any of its elements is undefined behavior. So yes, it's possible to create a buffer overflow in a `std::vector` if you treat it poorly.

```
v[0] = 1; // undefined because we're out of bounds
v[1] = 2; // as is this
```

Normally when adding elements to a `std::vector`, you use `push_back` or `emplace_back`, though, not direct element access

```
v.push_back(0);    // v is now 1 element long: { 0 }
v.emplace_back(1); // v is now 2 elements long: { 0 , 1 }
```

Using the `[]` operator *does* give you a reference to the underlying item, so you can use it both for retrieval and assignment, as long as you're sure the index is valid. You can use the `size()` function to determine what the appropriate max element index is (it's `size() - 1`)

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    v[i] = 10;
}
// v was size 2, we've replaced both elements at 0 and 1 with value 10
```

When using your `std::vector`, use the interface provided to you. Use `push_back` or `emplace_back` or `insert` to add elements. `pop_back` or `erase` to remove elements. A `std::vector` knows its `begin` and `end`, so you can iterate through it like this:

```
// prints the elements in the vector
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
   std::cout << *it << " ";
std::cout << "\n";
```

or a ranged-based for loop, since it provides the `begin()` and `end()` functions

```
// prints the elements in the vector
for (const auto& elem : v)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
std::cout << "\n";
```

It's possible to overrun your `std::vector` buffer, but very unlikely if you follow the rules. A `std::vector` is nicer than an array, so if you don't mind your elements existing in the free store (which is most non-high-performance applications), go for it. The ease of use and flexibility is well worth the extra overhead.

Further, because the data in your `std::vector` does NOT exist on the stack (while a local array is placed on the stack) you're very unlikely to overwrite your stack if you do overrun your `std::vector`. If you're lucky, your program will crash, but don't rely on this.

In conclusion, a `std::vector` can have its buffer overrun, but its interface makes it very hard to do so. If you ever do overrun its buffer, you're overwriting data in the free store, not on the stack, so you won't be modifying your return address. While you could potentially have a second item in the free store be written over by a `vector` buffer overrun, I believe this is non-deterministic. While anyone with access to your source code with an array could easily identify what input would produce a stack overwrite, if any.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for more information on the `std::vector` interface.